# $ o(ab)= o(ba)$, What about when $ab$ has infinite order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have been able to prove this when I say simply assume $o(ab)= n$, but I have been pondering the case of where $o(ab)$ is infinite?

Is this something that needs to be considered? And if not, why?

My rationale is that if $o(ab)$ is infinite, then no comparison can really be made with infinity. i.e. It can't really be said that two infinite things are equal. Is that correct?

Comment: $o(x)$ is infinite if and only if $x^n \neq e$for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Try to apply this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $ab$ has infinite order but $ba$ had finite order $n$. Then you can use your previous working to prove that $ab$ also had order $n$, a contradiction.

Hence, if $ab$ has infinite order then so does $ba$.

Answer (score 4):

The order is always the same, since $ab$ and $ba$ are conjugated elements through the automorphisms:
$$\phi_a : x \to a^{-1} x a,$$
$$\phi_b : x \to b^{-1} x b,$$
hence if $o(ab)$ is finite, $o(ba)|o(ab)$, so $o(ba)$ is finite, and since $o(ba)|o(ab)$, $o(ab)=o(ba)$.

If $o(ab)$ is infinite, $o(ba)$ is infinite, too.